# Azure - Automate service creation

Tags: azure, automation, azure-cli

Today I stumbled upon an issue with Azure's services: if I ever delete all my services and maybe want to recreate them in another account, how can I do that in a automatic and reliable way? I've seen Azure CLI as an option but it seems very basic, I've researched also the Docker containers which seem a better option but still I wanted to have a better overall view.

Is there a procedure to follow to create X Azure services in a script-like fashion?
Are there any "one-button-click" options or are bash scripts the only option?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are, basically, looking for arm templates, feel free to get back to me if you think  this isnt what you are looking for, but it really feels like the right thing

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yes, I too think what you are linking me to is what I was looking for. Just a quick question though, with a Resource Manager do I still have to use the Azure CLI to input commands that take in the .json files or is there any other way? Would it be a good idea to create a big bash script for my project's infrastructure? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: yeah (cli\powershell\SDK all work), i'm using powershell scripts to kick that off, but I'm mostly using big templates, not individual\modular templates. I was trying that, and I did find its really hard to reuse them.

Comment: @4c74356b41 Ok, thanks a lot for the clear and straightforward answers, really helped!

Comment: I would add using azure devops is a good resource.